# Read Safari extension version from the extension code itself

Tags: safari, version

I would like to report used extension version to service.
It there any way to read extension version number from within the extension?

Comment: biesiad - have you found a way to do this?
I'm having the same problem - in my extension's JavaScript code, I would like to read the 'CFBundleVersion' value (from Info.plist) and report it to my server. I just can't find the JavaScript API to read the Info.plist settings.
Thx

Comment: Not really... I use Settings.plist, and update it in build process. You can access it from extension:  safari.extension.settings.getItem('myExtensionVersionKey');

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the version using the `displayVersion` property of the `SafariExtension` class.

```
console.log(safari.extension.displayVersion);
// => "1.0"
```

[API Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ExtensionClassRef/SafariExtension.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009681)

Comment: Only available since Safari 6.0

Answer (score 2):

You can make an XMLHttpRequest to `safari.extension.baseURI + "Info.plist"` and get the version field from there, although it's a little bit laborious.

Comment: Can the person who gave me my first negative vote make an explanation? My answer correctly answers the question, I have tested it myself, it works, and it is a completely valid way of getting the version number. Better than the other two alternatives, because: a) Saving it in the settings requires that you remember to write that setting manually and inconsistencies may occur. b) safari.extension.displayVersion only works on Safari 6.0 or newer, which is quite a new version of Safari.

Comment: I clicked it by mistake. Apply my edit so i can un-downvote. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Furthering @cprcrack's answer, if you're using jQuery in your extension and you're targeting Safari 5, you can get the version number like this:

```
jQuery.get(safari.extension.baseURI + 'Info.plist', function(data){
    $('dict > key', data).each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == 'CFBundleShortVersionString') {
            var versionNumber = $(this).next().text();
            // Do something with versionNumber here
        }
    });
});
```